# Popular JSP/Servlet/Portlet Error Log Viewer?

Tags: java, error-reporting, error-logging

After reading the latest Coding Horror post I wondered if there was a Java-based version of ELMAH out there in the open source community?  A configurable JSP/Servlet/Portlet WAR that I can just drop into most servers and have a nice GUI for viewing the logs in the system.  Anyone have a project to recommend?

> #### Duplicate of
>
> [Exception Driven Programming in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760397/exception-driven-programming-in-java)

Comment: Interested in this too, but I doubt there's a solution as simple as ELMAH due to the architecture of servlet containers - it's not like you can have a class that simply can add itself as a listener to any Exceptions - the container doesn't offer anything simple like that

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760397/exception-driven-programming-in-java

Answer (score 2):

http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/index.php