# Exception Driven Programming in Java

Tags: c#, java

I just finished reading [Exception Driven Programming](https://blog.codinghorror.com/exception-driven-development/) and I'm wondering about something like [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/archive/p/elmah/) for Java. Did you know it?

Interesting features:

- A web page to remotely view the
  entire log of recoded exceptions
- A web page to remotely view the full
  details of any one logged exception
- An e-mail notification of each error
  at the time it occurs
- An RSS feed of the last 15 errors
  from the log
- other interface (JSON, RESTful interface, etc)
- A number of backing storage
  implementations for the log,
  including in-memory, JDBC, JMS, etc
- open source

**NOTE**

log4j is for logging, it is not an integrated solution for exception handling

Comment: heh, me too. I guess log4j does something like the same. But does ELMAH do more, like automagically log stuff to something with nice reporting?

Comment: there something like ELMAH for java?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761484/is-there-anything-like-elmah-for-java

Comment: What about combining Log4j and Quartz scheduling as an exception reporting solution?

Comment: why Quartz? please explain it better

Comment: Quartz can help in job scheduling i.e. categorizing different types of exceptions and send a e-mail report to their respective developers in-charge!

Comment: @dfa Have you made any progress on this front? If no solution exists, this would be an excellent problem to address in an open source project. Would you be interested in forming a project?

Comment: @Greg, I started writing thinking and designing some code java, nothing serious :(

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I don't see an accepted answer so...

I'm pleased to announce v3.0 of [LogDigger Connector](http://logdigger.com) library that:

- In case of an error, collects request-level data and logs.
- Can use memory or JDBC for storage.
- Has a built-in web interface (similar to ELMAH).
- Can send notifications via email, you can collect them using RSS or implement your own mechanism.
- Can track user actions and have the recent usage history included with the error report.
- Is quite lightweight (500KB) an has no external dependencies (except JDBC driver obviously and JavaMail API if you want to send email).