# Is there anything like ELMAH for Java?

Tags: java, exception, elmah

#### Duplicate:

[Exception Driven Programming in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760397/)

I have been looking at [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and was wondering what kinds of similar applications are available for Java.

Thanks for the recommendations for log4j and other frameworks.  Like the author of the post this question duplicates, I'm just looking to see if a more full-featured solution exists rather than having to roll my own (which of course I may do if there's nothing comparable).

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760397/exception-driven-programming-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Java logging frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Logging_Frameworks) page on Wikipedia it compares a few different loggers and their features.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). It's flexible enough to do pretty much anything you need, and it's stable and proven.